# XDBC app server showing only 2 active threads over MarkLogic XDBC admin console

Tags: java, marklogic

Our multi-threaded Java application is using the Java XCC library. Over MarkLogic admin console under status tab only 2 threads are shown as active while the application is running, that is the most probable reason of bottleneck in our project. Please advise what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To effectively run xcc requests in parallel you need to make sure you are using separate Sessions for each thread.  See: 
https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/Session.html

Having only 2 active threads running is not necessarily a sign of a problem, its possible that your requests are being processed as fast as you issue them and read the response. If your queries are fast enough there is no need for more threads.  Without more information about your queryies, response times and server load its not possible to say if there is a bottleneck or not.  How many threads are you running ? Compare the response time as you increase threads.  Check that you have sufficient network IO so that your requests are not bottlenecked in the network layer.

I suggest profiling your queries and using the Performance History console to see if the server is running at high utilization.  Try increasing the number of client threads, possibly running them from different servers.